FLutter riverpod: initial async provider
I am trying to use riverpod my project , Now I want to use an async provider , Since I need to send data to provider, I have to use a family provider like this:
@riverpod
class MyProvider extends _$MyProvider {
  @override
  FutureOr<MyModel> build(Model model) {
    return getAllModel(model);
  }

The problem is here , when all time I want to use this provider I need to use it like this:
ref.read(myProviderProvider(""-> I have to send data));

I mean I need to send data from its contractor , but I just read or use provider state. Is it possible to fix this?
If I don't send my model from build method I have to set s state to provider, the state must be MyModel() , but I have multiy required object inside it and I have to set a value inside model , dummy value , I do not like this way , Is it other or best way ?

Your build can get data from three places... the family (which obviously be the same every time), globals, or other providers (via ref.watch).

You can use an other provider to save Model and read it from build  method in MyProvider.

I think the provider could be as follows:
import ....
part ....

@riverpod
class MyProvider extends _$MyProvider{ 
  @override
  Future<MyModel> build(MyKey key) => _fetch(key);

  Future<MyModel> _fetch(MyKey key) async {
    .....
    return MyModel( .... );
    );
  }
}

Then, in your Widget class (I use riverpod annotations, they are very handly):
import ....

part ....

@cwidget
Widget _myScreen(
  BuildContext context,
  WidgetRef ref, {
  MyKey theKey,
}) =>
    switch (ref.watch(
        myProviderProvider.call(theKey)) {
      AsyncData(:final value) => _buildWithData(context, ref, value),
      AsyncError(:final error) => Text('Error: $error'),
      _ => const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
    };

Widget _buildWithData(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, MyModel model) =>
    MyModelWidget(
      model: model,
    );

